Replacing aircon capacitor, using off brand same spec vs lower/higher spec from correct brand?
The capacitors for an aircon have failed and I was wondering what would be better in repairing the aircon?
The spec are 450 volt 500uF (K)
The original manufacturer does not make the exact same spec anymore.
The options available:

Use the correct spec from an off brand (possibly lower quality) manufacturer.

Buy a capacitor with spec 450 volt 470uF from the original manufacturer.

Buy a capacitor with spec 450 volt 550uF from the original manufacturer.


If buying the wrong spec from the original manufacturer is best, is it better to go higher or lower uF and why?
From an electrical engineering and physics perspective what is the way to go?

If (K) is part of the code, K means 10%. Both options are within tolerance.
I assume this is a starting capacitor (this can be known from the type, and wiring diagram), the tolerance of which isn't crazy anyway.

First, if you can contact the original manufacturer, ask for their recommendation for your make and model of A/C.
I expect a bit higher capacitance and at least the  same voltage would be preferable.
You could also try visiting a local HVAC supply wholesaler and see what they have in stock. Chances are they have a good selection for their contractor customers, and it's not uncommon (at least around here) that they are willing to sell to individuals (though you may or may not get the same price as the contractor, probably quite a bit higher). My last choice would be some place like Amazon for an unknown brand (though I did pick up an eBay or FB market dual cap one time from a local guy in his driveway in the interests of expediency- it's still working).
This is in contrast to run capacitors, which should be within a tight tolerance of the nominal value for the motor or the motor can overheat.

Flip a coin. Ideally one with three sides.
I would order the one with the fastest delivery. Get a spare at the same time.

I'm not sure that this answers the question, which was looking for From an electrical engineering and physics perspective what is the way to go?
